# Get reference to object when chaining initiation and function c++

Tags: lambda, sfml

I have searched for quite some time now and tried everything I could think of.
I am currently developing a small game that have several buttons that I have to keep track of, The only difference between all these button are simply 1 function that include what should happend when it gets clicked. I could of course make several classes that inherit from a base Button class.

But I wanted to try using lambda instead to solve this, I currently have a vector that holds all my buttons. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the reference to the object.

```
buttons.push_back(new Button(542, 270, 40, 30, "-")
    ->enableClick([this]() {this->setText("asd")};
```

I can't run this of course since "this" will refer to object I'm in, but I can't figure out how I can do this in a nice way...
I could of course do

```
Button* button = new Button(462, 270, 40, 30, "-");
button->enableClick([button]() {button->setText("asd"); });
buttons.push_back(button);
```

but then I have to write 3 lines instead of 1, not that its really a HUGH issue, but I'm sure there must be some better way than I have thought of.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Two lines: `Button* button = buttons.push_back(new Button(542, 270, 40, 30, "-")); button->enableClick([button]() { button->setText("asd"); });` Which is pretty much what you had anyway.

Comment: @Ryan O'Hara Hi, thanks for the fast response, unfortunately didn't your solution work as push_back returns void. But it helped me came up with my current solution `buttons.push_back(new Button(622, 270, 40, 30, "+"));
 buttons.back()->enableClick([buttons.back()]() {
  Code ...
 });`

Comment: So `enableClick` returns the original `Button`, then? (Your first example’s braces and parentheses are misnested/missing, so it’s hard to tell.)